# What's render props, how is it different from high order components?

Tags: reactjs, render

It seems [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) have not get enough traction so far, however, it's widely used by prestigious react libraries, like `react-router 4`, `react motion` etc. And react site also have a dedicated section for it, any reason for this emerged pattern, how is compared to commonly known HOC (high order component) pattern?

Answer (score 16):

Leave an answer for my research, different answers & discussions are highly welcome!

HOC borrows the concept from [High Order Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function):

> a higher-order function (also functional, functional form or functor) is a function that does at least one of the following:
>
> - takes one or more functions as arguments (i.e., procedural parameters),
> - returns a function as its result.[disputed – discuss]

---

#### HOC

> A higher-order component (HOC) is an advanced technique in React for reusing component logic.

Originates from this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775).

This pattern is about **STATIC** composition. Core/reusable logic are encapsulated in the HOC, while leaving the moving parts to the component.

Use [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) from react router as an example:

> withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.
>
> // This gets around shouldComponentUpdate
>
> withRouter(connect(...)(MyComponent))

Now you get an enhanced MyComponent back which has the props of `{ history, match, location, ...connectProps, ...ownProps }` passed by the router HOC.

A common approach is to

```
compose(
  connect( ... ),
  enhance( ... ),
  withRouter( ... ),
  lifecycle( ... ),
  somethingElse( ... )
)(MyComponent);
```

The great part is that you can infinitely compose those HOCs with a [compose utility](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/compose.md) to get a final enhanced version of your component, and your component will get knowledge about redux store, react router etc injected from the new component returned by HOC.

The downside of the approach is that:

1. The behavior of the component is defined before runtime thus lost the power of react's rendering lifecycles, say you can't do something like:

   ```
   compose(
     this.state.shouldConnect && connect( ... ),
     this.state.shouldEnhance && enhance( ... ),
     this.state.shouldWithRouter && withRouter( ... ),
     ...
   )(MyComponent);
   ```

   since `state`/`props` is not available before your code runs.
2. Indirection & Naming collisions.

> using a HOC with ES6 classes poses many of the same problems that mixins did with createClass, just re-arranged a bit.
>
> HOCs introduce a lot of ceremony due to the fact that they wrap components and create new ones instead of being mixed in to existing components.

---

#### Render Props

> A render prop is a function prop that a component uses to know what to render.

First adopted by [react-motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion), early seen in [Dan's Gist](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/b0c060edf413fe23db0a#gistcomment-1410409) few weeks before first commit of redux.

This pattern is about **DYNAMIC** composition. Core/reusable logics stays in the component while the moving parts get passed as a callback prop.

**You can create HOCs through render props.**

Still use withRouter as an example:

```
const withRouter = Component => {
  const C = props => {
    const { wrappedComponentRef, ...remainingProps } = props;
    return (
      <Route
        render={routeComponentProps => (
          <Component
            {...remainingProps}
            {...routeComponentProps}
            ref={wrappedComponentRef}
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  };
  ...
  return hoistStatics(C, Component);
};
```

**While the opposite is not true.**

```
<Connect render={connectPropsMergedWithState => {
  <Enhance render={enhancePropsMergedWithState => {
    <WithRouter render={routerPropsMergedWithState => {
      <Lifecycle render={lifecyclePropsMergedWithState => {
        <SomethingElse render={somethingElsePropsMergedWithState => {
          ...
        }/>
        ...
      }/>
      ...
    }/>
    ...
  }/>
  ...
}/>
```

Though it might look not so good, it has lots of gains.

1. It has better **explicitness**, since we can see what's exactly passed as parameter to the render props.
2. Because of 1, it saves us from potential props **collisions**.
3. It's dynamic, we can pass whatever we like (including `state`/`props`) to render props.

The commonly known downside is [performance optimization is tricky](https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/1e7e22cbd92ba132dbbff893f0b51d7b), since what props to receive is deferred to runtime. And it's probably not a good idea to do any premature optimization, but that might be totally another topic.

<sub>If you agreed upon the direction move of react router from 3 to 4, render props might be your jam.</sub>

#### References:

1. https://cdb.reacttraining.com/use-a-render-prop-50de598f11ce
2. https://reactrocket.com/post/turn-your-hocs-into-render-prop-components

Comment: I'm downright shocked that a) the typically overzealous mods didn't flag the question as too broad, and b) that this excellent write up doesn't have any upvotes.
Edit: Ah, I just noticed you wrote the question and answered it yourself; why not write a blog post instead?

Comment: @ParkerAult It will be great if this answer could help a bit, as you assumed, I had the same question some days ago and it was marked as too broad, since my initial attempt was looking for an answer, I did some research and left it here for better answers, I still think it's a reasonable question w/ lots of great thoughts to come from different folks :)

Comment: I agree that this is a reasonable question, as it seems to be a design pattern that's expanding in popularity.

Would I be correct in saying that the 'render props' pattern is the same as 'Functions as Children' due to the fact children acts as a regular prop and can be passed any data (a function in this case) and can therefore be called like a render prop would be.

Comment: @tomhughes of course, they're exactly the same thing. more importantly is that as you tell, they're actually very generic design patterns w/ react sugar. HOCs are just high order functions that resembles *Decorator*/mixin pattern, while render props(child as function) are callbacks that offers Inversion of Control to the component clients.